# Archiving data in SQL Server with stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, archive

Database in SQL Server 2014 has one table and is consuming around 17-20 GB of disk space each day. Assuming that level of usage remains fairly consistent  and not accounting for lower usage on weekends/holidays.

That would mean I am looking at requiring around 7.3 TB of space to house 1 year of table data. I want to figure out long term strategy is going to be for this, including archiving (when/where/how). The database currently contains just a tad over 1 billion rows.

I am trying to write a stored procedure to archive data in other table but I can do it once with my code. Later if I want I have to create one more table each time.

```
create PROC [dbo].[ArchiveData_auditlog1]  
(  
    @CutOffDate datetime = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF @CutOffDate IS NULL 
    BEGIN
        SET @CutOffDate = DATEADD(mm, -8, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF @CutOffDate > DATEADD(mm, -3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR ('Cannot delete orders from last three months', 16, 1)
            RETURN -1
        END
    END

    BEGIN TRAN

                SELECT * into  [dbo].[archive_auditlog2]

        FROM [dbo].[AuditLog_test]
        WHERE timestamp < @CutOffDate

        IF @@ERROR <> 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRAN
            RAISERROR ('Error occured while copying data to dbo.archive.account', 16, 1)
            RETURN -1
        END

        DELETE [dbo].[AuditLog_test]
        WHERE timestamp < @CutOffDate

        IF @@ERROR <> 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRAN
            RAISERROR ('Error occured while deleting data from dbo.archive.account', 16, 1)
            RETURN -1
        END

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRAN
        RETURN 0
    END
end
```

My question is what will be best way to fix problem, table has no dependency on other tables and has primary key on Id. I want to archive data based on timestamp column.

If I have to do partitioning how can I partition this big table, how can I migrate data to archive server.

Comment: [Partitioning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx)

Comment: I agree with Michael Green's comment about using paritioning - check out Dan Guzman's excellent articles on the Internet about partitioning in general and specifically about the Range Right Sliding Window - http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2008/09/17/Automating-RANGE-RIGHT-Sliding-Window-Maintenance.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by archive? Do you want to delete the data?

Moving it to another db or server will still take up the same space. It may improve performance but you're just moving the problem around.

Do you need the data in its original form? Can you aggregate the data to reduce the number of rows?

If you do move the data to another table you may find a clustered columnstore may give better compression and save disk space.

Personally i would be using ssis and not  a sp using linked servers. As you have a primary key id be using that as a way of identifying what has been inserted and then can be deleted from the original table. An index on the column you are using for date range would be extremely beneficial. Id also consider using smaller batches such as one days worth at a time.

Comment: I want to keep data in other database,keeping 6 months old data in other server.i need in original form as it is health care so we may need data anytime. I tried columnstore index it just crashes server don't know why.so its not recommended in my environment.

Comment: Id try again with the clustered index on your archive server with a small insert.

Comment: can we archive data into other server as i read partitioning can be done with in same database.

Comment: If i read your comment correctly: Yes you could partition the table in the Production server as well as archive to another server. Partitioning will help performance, but won't save you space.